# Create X.509 key in java

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have followed the instruction for [creating x509 cert](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_&_Categorization_Apps/0010_GettingStarted/0015_Create_an_Agg_&_Cat_integration/0010_Creating_X.509_Public_Certificates#Java), however, after uploading the cert, i get

> Your x.509 certificate is invalid. Please upload a new certificate

Anyone seeing the same?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide more details about your certificate:

1) Was it a valid X.509 certificate, base64 encoded ( PEM ) format with 1024 bytes key size ?

Also the link you posted is incorrect for the documentation. It is here :

[Create X509 Certificate](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/index.php?title=0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0020_Aggregation_&_Categorization_Apps/0010_GettingStarted/0015_Create_an_Agg_&_Cat_integration/0010_Creating_X.509_Public_Certificates)

2) Is the error occuring at the time of uploading CERT or at the time of registering ( clicking on the submit button ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can always just export the public key only from the PEM and upload that.
You would need to submit a support ticket for us to investigate your cert as we would need to take a look at it.

I have followed the .Net self sign instructions with no issues. However others have had issues with PEM. Follow them to the letter, or like I said export the pub cert as text. that should work.

regards,
Jarred